# Pass Powershell script to batch file

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm trying to create a working PowerShell script. However, it doesn't quite work correctly in the function, and we think it's because of the type of format.

Could you help me pass this function to a cmd/batch command?

```
$datos = quser
foreach($id in $datos)
{
    $nom = ""
    $userid = $id -split '\s+'
    $ad = $userid[0].Replace(">","")
    if ($ad -eq $usuario)
    {
        $nom = $ad
        $userid[2]
    }
}
```

It is a function to get only the ID from the `quser` command utility.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately your question lacks some information. How is a batch file involved? What do you want to do? What is successful, what fails? Please give further information not in comments. Instead edit your question and update everything that readers may help to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell will output the active console session ID from quser.exe.  Save to file Get-Qusers.ps1

```
$pattern = '(?<username>.*?) {2,}(?<sessionname>.*?) {2,}(?<id>.*?) {2,}(?<state>.*?) {2,}(?<idletime>.*?) {2,}(?<logontime>.*?)$'
$quser = quser.exe

($quser | Select-String -Pattern $pattern ).Matches | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Username    = $_.Groups['username'].Value.Trim() -replace '>'
        Sessionname = $_.Groups['sessionname'].Value
        Id          = $_.Groups['id'].Value
        State       = $_.Groups['state'].Value
        IdleTime    = $_.Groups['idletime'].Value
        LogonTime   = $_.Groups['logontime'].Value
    }
} |
    Where-Object { $_.Sessionname -eq 'console' } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id
```

To run the ps1 script in a batch file and save the Id to a variable

```
echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('powershell.exe -f get-qusers.ps1') do (SET QuserId=%%g)
echo %QuserId%
```